# C# await connection.OpenAsync() hangs application

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task

I tried multiple solutions in SO, but didn't work. Inside my api, I am trying to call a method asynchrnously on another thread and return the main thread.

```
// in a normal method... I can't use await here
string connectionString =_dbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => CallMethodAsync(connectionString)); 

public static async Task CallMethodAsync(string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        await connection.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        using (SqlCommand command2 = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            // this doesn't execute!
        }
    }
}
```

The code runs but hangs at the await connection.OpenAsync() and not execute the next block
What's the problem?

Comment: Probably your connectionString is wrong

Comment: It's likely timing out connecting to SQL Server. Check that your server hostname is correct in connection string?

Comment: Are you capturing the retuned `Task`? If so, it may be marked as `faulted` with an `Exception` that you can examine. See [SqlConnection.OpenAsync Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.openasync(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: feel dumb. thinking it will throw an exception if the connection is invalid, was a wrong assumption on my part. I needed to include the password. Thank you guys! Someone put it as an answer

Comment: it will throw an exception, but the question becomes: where does that exception go to? what is the call stack in which the exception happens?
 when you're involving worker threads and async, it gets tricky